# Average Internet Download Speeds for All Countries

Tags: internet

I've already explored Akamai's State of the Internet Reports and the ITU's ICT Indicators Database, and tried to access Ookla's old data which is not offline. Is there anyone who can recommend where I could find average internet speeds by country?

Comment: I added an [answer](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/9019/1511) that has monthly aggregate download/upload speeds for each country (see the datamarket part of the answer at the bottom)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately I contacted the editor of the Akamai State of the Internet report to explain the purpose of my research and he was willing to provide aggregate data by country for average speed and average peak speed. Very good quality data :-)