# Ookla/NetIndex data dump

Tags: data-request, internet, global

A wonderful resource that earlier used to exist for researching global Internet speed and quality was Ookla's NetIndex. Ookla has [discontinued](http://www.netindex.com/) public download, I believe since 2015. Does anyone have a dump of the last publicly available source data?

Answer (score 1):

The [Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org) from the [Internet Archive](http://web.archive.org) has many snapshots of netindex.com

After a quick check, one of the latest snapshots with a still-active bulk download seems to be from late 2014 or 2013

```
http://web.archive.org/web/20141125201822/http://www.netindex.com/

http://web.archive.org/web/20131205024304/http://www.netindex.com/source-data/
```

Unfortunately, it seems there is no quick-fix because the downloads weren't archived. In the source code, you can see one page

```
http://web.archive.org/web/20131205024304/http://www.netindex.com/source-data/
```

that has a link to the [Google Public Data](http://web.archive.org/web/20131204171527/http://www.google.com/publicdata/explore?ds=z8ii06k9csels2_&ctype=l&strail=false&nselm=h&met_y=avg_download_speed&scale_y=lin&ind_y=false&rdim=country&tdim=true&hl=en&dl=en&iconSize=0.5&uniSize=0.035) site, but no luck

---

A monthly-aggregated dataset is still hosted on [datamarket](https://datamarket.com/data/set/1gyb/global-broadband-performance#!ds=1gyb!1c89=1:1c8a&display=line), I made a csv export and it's hosted on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/raw/VU0VmEES) (sorry for the horrible pivot)

[image]

Comment: Hi philshem... Actually, archive.org did archive the zipped data folders, but you can't download them with a browser. I checked the page source and managed to download using aria2c. The strange things is all the archived data, regardless of date, are from one particular date (2011, I can't remember the dd/mm). Thanks for the datamarket pointer. But it too seems to be commercial,  not?